# No idea why this code throws a NumberFormatException. (Valid input)

Tags: java, parseint

So I'm reading this:

```
10011011001;0110,1001,1001,0,10,11
```

And running this code on it:

```
        String[] parts = line.split(";");
        System.out.println("Part 1 = " + parts[0]);
        System.out.println("Part 2 = " + parts[1]);
        System.out.println(isNumeric(parts[0]));
        int original = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        System.out.println("Original = " + original);
```

The `isNumeric` method is what I wrote to debug.

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The output:

```
Line = 10011011001;0110,1001,1001,0,10,11
Part 1 = 10011011001
Part 2 = 0110,1001,1001,0,10,11
true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10011011001"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at str_substitution.main(str_substitution.java:45)
```

No idea why this exception, clearly the string is numeric, and valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

10,011,011,001 is too big to fit in a 32-bit integer.

Perhaps you mean to use a `long` and `parseLong()`?

Or did you actually mean to parse it as a binary number (decimal 1241) with `parseInt(parts[0], 2)`?

[Here you can check the minimum and maximum values for each Java data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: I wanted to parse it as an int itself, or now maybe a long.

Answer (score 3):

Your number is 10 billion, while integer max for Java is roughly -2b - 2b. Thus it is unparsable.

Perhaps you want to use [`parseInt(String s,int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to read it in as a binary number? Or `parseLong()`.

From Javadoc (example of similar case) -

```
parseInt("2147483648", 10) throws a NumberFormatException
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `Long.parseLong()` instead of `Integer.parseInt()`?